# Trigger won't run in MySql WorkBench

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I have updated my question and still having the problem. Now it's showing my a red cross near VALUES. I don't know what wrong with the syntax

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER PendingPublish 
    AFTER INSERT ON TopicPending
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Topics (Title,Description,Question1,Qustion2,Question3,Question4,UserID)
VALUES (NEW.Title,NEW.Descritpion,NEW.Question1,NEW.Question2,NEW.Question3,NEW.Question4,NEW.UserID) 
  FROM TopicPending  
  WHERE NEW.TopicApproved = 'YES' 
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but fairly certain `INSERTED` is specific to MS Sql Server , and not supported by MySQL.

Comment: In MySQL you use `NEW.columnName` to access values being inserted.

Comment: @Barmar NEW. in front of inserted query columns or select query columns?

Comment: @samscoot There is no `SELECT`. Just use `VALUES (NEW.Title, NEW.Description, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger has the new value from table TopicPending so to access the column TopicApproved, you only need to prefix it with New.   No need to select it. See below.

```
IF NEW.TopicApproved = 'YES' THEN
  INSERT INTO Topics (Title,Description,Question1,Qustion2,Question3,Question4,UserID)
  VALUES (NEW.Title,NEW.Description,NEW.Question1,NEW.Question2,NEW.Question3,NEW.Question4,NEW.UserID);
END IF;
```